# Find coefficients $a,b,c$ and the roots of polynomial: $f(x)=ax^5+3x^4+bx^3+4x^2+3x+c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Find coefficients $a,b,c$ and the roots of polynomial:
>
> $$f(x)=ax^5+3x^4+bx^3+4x^2+3x+c$$
>
> with integer coefficients, if it's known that $f$ has triple integer root.

(I'm not sure if that was the correct translation to english so my apologies for any mistakes).

What I tried: I found first and second derivation:

$$f'(x)=5a^4+12x^3+3bx^2+8x+3$$
$$f''(x)=20ax^3+36x^2+6bx+8$$

If polynomial $g(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ has integer root $k$, then $a_0$ is divisible by $k$.
That means that the triple integer root of $f$ divides both of the constant coefficients of both $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$, $3$ and $8$.

That means that the only possible solution for $k$ is $k=\pm1$.

Do I now do two cases, each with different $k$, and solve the three equations $f(x)=0$, $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ and see which one of them is correct or is there another way to immediately know which of the two possible roots is the correct one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see an immediate way to see which is correct, I would just try both.

Comment: $p(x) = x^5+3x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2+ 3x + 1 = (x+1)^3(x^2+1)$ clearly works...

Comment: For $k=1$, we have $f'(x)=0\iff 5a+3b+23=0$ and $f''(x)=0\iff 10a+3b+22=0$ implying $a=\frac 15$. So, $k\not=1$.